# Where does the error parameter from the first argument of a callback function come from?

Tags: node.js, callback

My understanding is when the function we call is finished executing, the call back function is called. At some places the callback function accepts two arguments one being the error argument and the other being something else. From where are these arguments passed to the callback function.

Eg:

```
request({URL},(error,response)=>{
// some function
})
```

```
db.collection("users").insertOne({
name:"adam"
age:22},(error,result)=>{
//some function}
)
```

Are these argument names key words or are they by default sent as error as the first argument and so on..

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have keyword parameters, they're always positional. The values are passed to the callback when it's invoked by whatever you're passing it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about where do `error` and `result` come from.

This is a standard js callback style. `error` will be `null` if no `insertOne` executed successfully, and will be an error if something went wrong.

For example, this is kind of `insertOne`

```javascript
const insertOne = (params, callback) => {
    try {
        // Do insert logic and set result to 'result' variable
        callback(null, result)
    } catch (error) {
        callback(error, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this to be expected in all functions with the callback pattern?

Comment: No, but it's a common way. Now async/await approach is also popular.